# Vagrant Box Breaking After Knife Cookbook Installs

Tags: centos, chef-infra, vagrant, knife

I'm a Vagrant n00b who's having issues getting Vagrant and Chef's `knife` command to play nice together as I'm setting up a pretty simple CentOS LAMP box using chef-solo.

Here's a quick rundown of ths issue:

1. I've created a basic Vagrantfile using the CentOS 6.3 w/ Chef base box on vagrantbox.es. You can see the basics in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3974036).
2. I've downloaded all the cookbooks via `knife cookbook site install nameofcookbook` using a configuration that puts them in `./chef/cookbooks`.
3. I've successfully run `vagrant up` to You can see the basics in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3974036).
4. I've tested apache, php, etc. All good.
5. Now comes the trick: **with the VM running, I run knife to add another package (in this case i3)**.
6. From here on, Vagrant fails to perform various tasks in the VM:
7. When I run `vagrant provision` I get an error like this

> ```
> The chef binary (either `chef-solo` or `chef-client`) was not found on
> the VM and is required for chef provisioning. Please verify that chef
> is installed and that the binary is available on the PATH.
> ```

When I run `vagrant halt` I get an error that the ssh command exited with a non-zero error code.

I am able to run `vagrant ssh` however, and confirm that (a) chef-solo does, in fact, exist in the box and (b) I can shutdown via the commandline in the box.

When I run `vagrant up` I get an error like this:

> ```
> The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
> Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
> mkdir -p /vagrant</li>
> ```
>
> I'm stumped. I've had this happen on two boxes already, and I know that Knife and Vagrant should be able to play well together.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help much appreciated, I've very excited about digging into Vagrant!

Answer (score 17):

```
chef.add_recipe "sudo"
```

Nuked your sudo file after the first run.

Add the appropriate json to your vagrant file for your vagrant user.

Something like:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|

  # add your recipes
  # chef.add_recipe "foo"
  # chef.add_role   "bar"
  chef.json = {
    "authorization" => {
        "sudo" => {
            "users" => [ "vagrant" ],
            "passwordless" => true,
        }
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the "Nuked your sudo file after the first run"

Comment: @Vdt The chef sudo recipe updated /etc/sudoers which removed the "vagrant" user's sudo permissions. unless you add that user as shown above, you won't be able to run chef again as it requires sudo.

Comment: chef-solo or chef-client is not found at all in VM, it doesn't seems to be like your json install chef-solo/chef-client is it?

Comment: @holms yes, your VM needs to have chef installed for the above to work.

Comment: I've used this `config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest` in my Vagrant file, and installed vagrant plugin before `vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus`

Comment: I actually tried a few things before using this approach see (links below).  _This is definitly the cleanest solution I have found._ **Resources:** [possible fix via recipie... didn't work for me](http://www.porkchopsandpaintchips.com/2013/08/01/vagrant-chef-and-sudoers-oh-my/) and [a better explanation of how the sudo cookbook locks chef out of the system](http://clarkdave.net/2013/02/vagrant-chef-and-the-sudo-cookbook/)